# What is use of isExecuted() in ADF ViewObjectImpl class

Tags: oracle-adf

I want to understand utility of  isExecuted() in ADF's ViewObjectImpl  class.
The documentation is very sparse(*[Indicates whether the row set has been executed or not](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1221/adf/api-reference-model/oracle/jbo/server/ViewRowSetImpl.html#isExecuted--)*) and I couldn't get my doubts cleared.

As per documentation, only if row set is executed at least once it will return true. But, I am seeing that as soon as my application module is created, a  view Object which is housed in the application module, is returning "isExecuted() = true " .. Is this expected or is there any setting because of which this is happening ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is hard to see purely via the Application Module Tester. 
But if you have data controls based on your AM and use them on an interface (such as a UI page), you can check the working of the `isExecuted` method.

On your user interface, you can create a basic page that does not bind to any of the data controls based on the VO's - but only to a simple AM operation that you expose via AM's client interface:

```
public void showIsExecuted() {        
    System.out.println("*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() DepartmentsView1:" + this.getDepartmentsView1().isExecuted());
    System.out.println("*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() DepartmentsView2:" + this.getDepartmentsView1().isExecuted());
    System.out.println("*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() ViewObj1:" + this.getViewObj1().isExecuted());
}
```

On a UI page (view1.jsf), you call only this method without using any of the VO based data controls and your output should show this:

```
*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() DepartmentsView1:false
*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() DepartmentsView2:false
*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() ViewObj1:false
```

Now, on another UI page (e.g. view2.jsf), show some of the data from one or more of the VO's and also a button for the custom AM function. After running the page, you should get the below in logs (as expected):

```
*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() DepartmentsView1:true
*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() DepartmentsView2:true
*******TestAppModuleImpl::showIsExecuted() ViewObj1:false
```

For reference, this is what my design time setup (in JDeveloper 12.2.1.1) looks like :
[image]

**Also,** you can further tweak the options under AM -> General -> Tuning -> Customize Runtime Instantiation Behaviour